# What datastructure to use to store cached SQL-query in?

Tags: sql, delphi, delphi-2007

I want to use a datastructure like this:

```
  building string  (indexed)
  date     TDate   (indexed)
  room_id  integer (indexed)
  measurement_data -> various fields
```

To change a database query in that's in a remote SQL server.

This way I only have to query the database once for a given building and I can use a Delphi middleware application to hand out individual data items to a backend.

What kind of data structure would you recommend for storing this stuff, so that I can retrieve data items quickly.

I was thinking of putting it in a class with the above items and putting the objects in a TStringList, but then I only have 1 index on the data.
Because I'm retrieving individual items mostly I don't want to use a clientside DB.
Is there a better TList variant that will let me retrieve an item quickly.

In other words, `TStringlist` (with attached) objects only allows one index. (the string) is there a better List that will allow multiple indexes?

**EDIT**
`TCollection` sounds like a much better match, is that a good idea?

Comment: TClientDataSet is not an overengineering in this case

Comment: TClientDataset works like a charm, and does what I need esp. since it has findnearest. It fills an excel sheet interpolating missing values in record time. Will see how the speed issues go when scaling the application.

Comment: KbMemTable should be a good choice also...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In one of my old projects (around Delphi 7) I did this by having multiple `TList`s storing pointers to records. One of the lists owns the items and is responsible for cleanup, the others point to the same items but each list is sorted differently, serving as indexes for binary search lookup. Other then their order, the lists are identical and kept in sync - adding an item adds to all the lists, removing an item removes from all the lists.

Another option would be to use `TClientDataSet` or another in-memory dataset with indexing support.

Comment: Decided to go with TClientDataset. Looks like the proper solution for the problem.

Answer (score 1):

May be : [SynBigTable](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2010/03/22/Synopse-Big-Table-v1.3) a 'in Memory' fast table with fields,  indexes and search.

Comment: Will review this when I have time, for now I'm going with TClientDataset. just because that's what comes standard with delphi.

Comment: @Johan : Good choice, I use instead SynBigTable for performance needs, but it seems not to be a problem with your application.

Comment: turns out ClientDataset does not support more than 200.000 records, so I'm back to the drawing board :-). Let's see how that SynBigTable goes.

Comment: @Johan SynBigTable support millions records and is quite fast.